# What effect, if any, does dissipative absorption have on aurora borealis? Why don't we see more colors as a result?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, absorption

According to wikipedia, the aurora borealis is primarily caused by charged particles from the solar wind being redirected to the poles by earth's magnetic field and slamming into the nitrogen and oxygen atoms in the upper atmosphere. This slamming gives the electrons in those oxygen and nitrogen atoms enough energy to escape their electron clouds. The light comes from when electrons emit photons in order to rejoin an atom. Hence the colors, green corresponding to oxygen atom readmittance and purple to nitrogen

What I am wondering is what role dissipative absorption plays in the aurora borealis. I mean we have a bunch of accelerating charged particles right? Even if speed is constant their direction is changing due to the magnetic force and since they're charged they must be emitting some kind of em radiation right? Not to mention when the actual collisons take place between electrons.

Not all of this em radiation will correspond to the energy levels of nitrogen and oxygen right? So shouldn't we see more colors as all sorts of em radiation ought to be emitted?

If nothing else you would expect the electron clouds of oxygen and nitrogen to oscillate in response to the emitted em radiation of the incoming solar wind right?

Why do we tend to see only green and purple?